# No puedo conectar mi hosting con mi dominio?

Tags: html, dominio, godaddy, plesk

Lo que pasa es que tengo un dominio el cual es impulsodigno.org de hace ya algún tiempo y lo añadí a un hosting el cual adquirí recientemente (uso plesk), pero el problema es que no me da dirección ip al intentar acceder a la página, ya he intentado de todo y nada parece funcionar, he cambiado los nameserver del dns del dominio por los que te dan al adquirir el host, subí los archivos html al host de una forma correcta, ya configuré el hosting con todo lo que debía llevar 
 y nada, si alguien ha tenido algún problema similar les agradecería cualquier información.
Por cierto, ambos servicios los adquirí en godaddy.
Gracias

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deja los DNS de manera correcta y no los cambies, tengo entendido que puede tardar promedio de 1 dia.

Comment: Yo tenia un error similar cuando compre mi dominio y marqué al servicio técnico y me ayudó mucho. Creo que tuve que hacer una modificaciones en los DNS o la IP.

Comment: Gracias por ambos comentarios, he movido de todo y creo que mejor llamaré a soporte técnico

Comment: Ten en cuenta el comentario de @Kevin Delva

Comment: Al final fue problema de los registros del dns, estaban mal en el dominio ya que era un dominio antiguo y el registro A tenía otra ip, gracias a todos